# Get innerHtml of elements ignoring a specific id

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to get the `innerHTML` from a `div` but I need to ignore the `divs` inside it that have a specific id.

In the bellow sample, I need to get all `#data innerHtml` but ignore `div#ignoreme`.

```
<div id="data">
    <div id="ignoreme">ignore</div>
    <p>line</p>
    this is another line
</div>
```

I tried `doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='data']").SelectNodes("//*[not(@id='ignoreme')]");`

But it isn't working, this always returns the full html document (!?)

So, is this possible with html agility pack, XPath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
var sol = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='data']")
           .SelectNodes(".//*[not(@id='ignoreme')]").ToList();
```

Or you can do this instead:

```
var sol1 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='data']")
                .Descendants()
                .Where(p => p.Id != "ignoreme")
                .ToList();
```